# Параметр значения шаблона

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Почему параметр значения шаблона обязан быть константой, если создание кода выполняется во время выполнения?

```
template<int a>
void foo ()
{
    cout << a << endl;
}

int main()
{
    int b = 10;

    foo<b>();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: дратути, шаблоны разворачиваются на стадии компиляции

Comment: "создание кода выполняется во время выполнения" - это откуда вы такое взяли? Весь код "создается" во время компиляции.

Answer (score 0):

Вообще не понятно, что вы хотите написать.
Если вам необходима шаблонная функция печати, то вы неправильно делаете, надо вот так:

```
template<typename T>
void foo (const T& var)
{
    std::cout << var << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    int b = 10;

    foo(b);

    return 0;
}
```

При компиляции данного кода, шаблонная функция foo будет развернута для типа int.
По синтаксису шаблонов много информации в интернете.
http://cppstudio.com/post/5188/
https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A8%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8B_C%2B%2B

Comment: Мне не нужна шаблонная функция печати) Мне стало интересно, почему в параметр значения шаблона можно использовать только константные типы

Comment: т.е. если  `const int b = 10`  все работает

Comment: аргументом шаблона  может быть тип или  константный обьект.  Почему так?..  Представьте себе автоматизированный процесс производства шляп.  Все механизмы уже запрограммированы  на то как будут действовать( идентично понятию  "код выполняется во время компиляции"). Вам лишь остается ввести размер шляпы во время выполнения. Если размер во время производства будет меняться  непредсказумым образом, а не  по нашей команде  " сделать шляпы другого типа ", то сами понимаете что  получим...  Но в учебниках вы найдете  подробную информацию, только нужно брать и прочитать

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, спасибо